# No signature of method: static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String,

Tags: mobile, automation, katalon-studio

I'm using katalon to do some automation test for mobile app.
I used a mobile keyword in the if...else..., but it looks like the logic is not right.

```
Mobile.waitForElementPresent(findTestObject('Mobile_APP/App_Cart/Cart_Page/Cart_Header'), 40)

if(Mobile.verifyElementExist(findTestObject('Mobile_APP/App_Cart/QTY_on_Cart', 3))){

    int a = Integer.parseInt(Mobile.getText(findTestObject('Mobile_APP/App_Cart/QTY_on_Cart'), 3))

    for(int i = 0; i <a ; i++){

        Mobile.waitForElementPresent(findTestObject('Mobile_APP/App_Cart/Cart_Page/Delete_Product_Icon'), 10)

        Mobile.tap(findTestObject('Mobile_APP/App_Cart/Cart_Page/Delete_Product_Icon'), 3)

    }

    Mobile.tap('Mobile_APP/App_HomePage/Home_Icon_in_Footer', 3)

}
else {

    Mobile.tap('Mobile_APP/App_HomePage/Home_Icon_in_Footer', 3)

}
```

As my point, I thought is should be right.

But it didn't.

--Below is the error I got when running the case.

> 2019-10-18 12:50:31.388 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - ❌ Test Cases/App_AutoCases/TestCases/Cart/Cart_Case_002_Clear_all_Items FAILED.
>   Reason:
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer) values: [Mobile_APP/App_Cart/QTY_on_Cart, 3]
>   Possible solutions: findTestObject(java.lang.String), findTestObject(java.lang.String, java.util.Map), findRequestObject(java.lang.String, java.io.File)
>       at Cart_Case_002_Clear_all_Items.run(Cart_Case_002_Clear_all_Items:29)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:337)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:328)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:307)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:299)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:233)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:105)
>       at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
>       at TempTestCase1571374158460.run(TempTestCase1571374158460.groovy:21)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot some code there.

```
if(Mobile.verifyElementExist(findTestObject('Mobile_APP/App_Cart/QTY_on_Cart', 5))){
```

above code should be the first row.

And I've found the problem, the right code should be below:

```
if(Mobile.verifyElementExist(findTestObject('Mobile_APP/App_Cart/QTY_on_Cart'), 5)){
```